# using wsgen utility for generating webservice client classes

Tags: java, wsdl, wsgen

I have a web service implemented in this folder in this package hierarchy in eclipse:
src\hw2\agency\server
to generate the client classes using WSGEN utility, I entered the following command in cmd:

```
C:\Users\NOONA\workspace\HW2>wsgen -d . -keep -wsdl -classpath . hw2.agency.server.AgencyServiceServerImpl
```

but I get the following error:
Class not found: "hw2.agency.server.AgencyServiceServerImpl"
so I was wondering, what should I do to make it find the class?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the current directory to

```
C:\Users\NOONA\workspace\HW2\**bin**>
```